# How to use Associative Arrays in PL/SQL in a WHERE Condition such that Key-Value pairs of Associative array are Column names in my table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a question regarding my problem in using of Associative arrays inside a sql query.

I use ORDS (Oracle Rest Data Services) as my RESTApi Server. I can define variables in the query string.

Imagine that I pass my variable like this in the query string:

```
https://MY-HOST-ADDRESS:PORT/rest/v1/list?MyVariable=Value
```

I defined my associative array as below:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE xlatemap is TABLE OF VARCHAR2(64)
    INDEX BY VARCHAR2(64);

  col_xlate xlatemap;

BEGIN
  col_xlate('address')     := 'ci.CAMPUS';
  col_xlate('hostname')    := 'ci.VISIBLE_ID';
  col_xlate('serial')      := 'ci.SERIAL_NO';
```

What i would like to do is, getting user-friendly variable names (e.g. **address**, **hostname** and **serial**) in the query strings. Therefore I created this hashmap (associative_array).

My aim is to use this assoc array in my **WHERE** condition like below:

```sql
SELECT  ci.CAMPIS, ci.VISIBLE_ID, ci.SERIAL_NO
FROM    tableName as ci
WHERE   col_xlate('hostname') like 'RT-101'
```

Do you know how can I use it inside

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, an associative array is a PL/SQL data type and is not supported in SQL.

You can use collections and `VARRAY`s defined in the SQL scope in an SQL statement but not associative arrays as they can only be defined in a PL/SQL scope.

---

If you want the value from the associative array as the column name in the SQL then you will need to evaluate the value from the associative array in PL/SQL and use dynamic SQL to execute the generated query. (But you can't directly use the associative array in an SQL statement.)

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE xlatemap is TABLE OF VARCHAR2(64)
    INDEX BY VARCHAR2(64);

  col_xlate xlatemap;

  p_campis     TABLENAME.CAMPIS%TYPE;
  p_visible_id TABLENAME.VISIBLE_ID%TYPE;
  p_serial_no  TABLENAME.SERIAL_NO%TYPE;
BEGIN
  col_xlate('address')     := 'ci.CAMPUS';
  col_xlate('hostname')    := 'ci.VISIBLE_ID';
  col_xlate('serial')      := 'ci.SERIAL_NO';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT  ci.CAMPIS, ci.VISIBLE_ID, ci.SERIAL_NO
                     FROM    tableName ci
                     WHERE   ' || col_xlate('hostname') || ' like ''RT-101'''
  INTO p_campis, p_visible_id, p_serial_no;
  -- this may need to be BULK COLLECT INTO if you are going to return multiple rows.

  -- do something with the variables;
END;
/
```

---

If you want to do it in SQL then you'll need to use a collection (or `VARRAY`) defined in the SQL scope:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TYPE key_value_pair AS OBJECT(
  key   VARCHAR2(64),
  value VARCHAR2(64)
);

CREATE TYPE key_value_pair_table AS TABLE OF key_value_pair;
```

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( CAMPIS, VISIBLE_ID, SERIAL_NO ) AS
SELECT 'A1', 'A2', 'A3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B1', 'B2', 'B3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', 'C2', 'C3' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CASE ( SELECT value
              FROM TABLE(
                key_value_pair_table(
                  key_value_pair( 'address',  'CAMPIS' ),
                  key_value_pair( 'hostname', 'VISIBLE_ID' ),
                  key_value_pair( 'serial',   'SERIAL_NO' )
                )
              )
              WHERE key = 'hostname'
            )
       WHEN 'CAMPIS'     THEN campis
       WHEN 'VISIBLE_ID' THEN visible_id
       WHEN 'SERIAL_NO'  THEN serial_no
       END
       IN ( 'A2', 'B2' )
```

but it seems like you could just eliminate the array and just use a case statement:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CASE 'hostname' -- your variable
       WHEN 'address' THEN campis
       WHEN 'hostname'THEN visible_id
       WHEN 'serial'  THEN serial_no
       END
       IN ( 'A2', 'B2' )
```

**Output**:

Both output:

> ```
> CAMPIS | VISIBLE_ID | SERIAL_NO
> :----- | :--------- | :--------
> A1     | A2         | A3       
> B1     | B2         | B3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=09088d68d287a9816a6e358120a57d3f)*

Comment: Thanks @MT0, I will test your solution.